# Mongo Background/Foreground Indexing Updates

Tags: mongodb, indexing

Let's say I index my collection with **background** indexing.

`db.collection.ensureIndex({name: 1}, {background: true})`

After indexing completes, let's say that I write to this collection.

Will the index update be a **blocking** or **non-blocking** operation?

Conversely, what if I had performed a foreground index?

Comment: It will be a blocking operation, it does not continue to run in background once made

Comment: Any way to configure it to be non-blocking? If I'm concerned about the overhead of updating the index, should I run the index on my replica? Also, care to post as answer?

Comment: I'm not actually sure, I know that in 2.2 there was no way but maybe there is some kind of new change. There is no automated way demoting index updating to secondaries alone, default behavior is that they update indexes after the primary. Not sure how that would work